# WP_Query not showing after adding die() on ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm running a wp_query, it's working but at the end of the loop, it adds '0'. I've researched and found out that I need to add die() at the end of the ajax call function though it stops showing new results.

Here's my ajax call:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_events', 'filter_events');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_events', 'filter_events');

function filter_events() {
    $event_name = $_POST['event_name'];

    if (!empty($_POST['event_name'])) {
        $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            's' => $event_name,
        ]);

        $response = '';

        if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
            while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
                $response .= get_template_part( 'loop-templates/events', 'loop' );
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $response = 'empty';
        }

        //echo $response;
    }
    else {
        $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
        ]);

        if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
            while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
                $response .= get_template_part( 'loop-templates/events', 'loop' );
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $response = 'empty';
        }
        //echo $response;
    }
    die();
}
```

Here's my JS:

```
jQuery('.search-filter').on('keyup', function(e) {

    var data = jQuery(this).serialize();
    //console.log(data);
    var keyValue = jQuery(this).val();
    //console.log(keyValue);

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      action: 'filter_events',
      event_name: keyValue,
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res); 
        jQuery('.echo-events-wrapper').html(res);
    },
    error: function(res) {
        console.log(res); 
    },
  })
});
```

Here's my php:

```
                <div class="echo-events">
                    <h2>UPCOMING EVENTS</h2>
                    <div class="event-filter">
                        <input type="search" id="site-search" name="event_name" aria-label="Search through site content" class="search-filter">
                    </div>
                    <div class="echo-events-wrapper">
                        <?php filter_events(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Output before adding die() at the end of ajax call:

```
<div class="echo-events-wrapper">
   <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card">
         <div class="card-header" id="headingsample-event-2">
            <img src="http://sampleurl.test/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/event-thumbnail-130.jpg">
            <h3 class="mb-0">
               <a href="http://sampleurl.test/event/sample-event-2/">Sample Event 2</a>
               <div class="event-meta">
                  <span class="event-date">Thu February 25, 2021</span>
                  <div class="event-duration">
                     <span class="event-start">12:00 am</span> - 
                     <span class="event-end">7:00 pm</span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </h3>
            <button class="btn-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sample-event-2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="sample-event-2">
            <i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div id="sample-event-2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingsample-event-2" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
               <div class="event-links">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   0
</div>
```

**Updated ajax call:**

```
function filter_events() {
    $event_name = $_POST['event_name'];

    if (!empty($_POST['event_name'])) {
        $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            's' => $event_name,
        ]);
        ob_start();
        $response = '';
        if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
            while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'loop-templates/events', 'loop' );
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $response = 'empty';
        }
        $response = ob_get_clean();
        echo $response;
        wp_die();
    }
    else {
        $ajaxposts = new WP_Query([
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_key'      => 'event_date',
            'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
        ]);
        ob_start();
        $response = '';
        if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
            while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'loop-templates/events', 'loop' );
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            $response = 'empty';
        }
        $response = ob_get_clean();
        echo $response;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: No, using PHP’s own `die` is _not_ the appropriate thing to do here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/250280/best-way-to-end-wordpress-ajax-request-and-why

Comment: adding wp_die() just made it worse, it brought me to WP's error page

Comment: `$response .= get_template_part(…)` doesn’t do what you probably thought it does. This function does not return the content of the rendered template, but it only returns void when successful, and false otherwise. You are getting output, because those templates write directly to the output stream, not because your `$response` actually contained any meaningful data. (And your `echo $response;` are commented out as well.) If you want to capture the rendered output of your templates in a variable, you will need to use output buffering.

Comment: thanks @CBroe! However die() doesn't work on the second condition (else / if _POST is empty). It doesn't query anymore if I add die() below the echo $response. And it shows '0' at the end of the results when I don't add die(). Did I miss something?

Comment: No apparent reason why that second case should behave differently. Have you checked the actual response for any error messages? What you are doing at the beginning of your function is definitively the wrong way around (attempted read access to `$_POST['event_name']`, _before_ you check if that is not empty), so that could perhaps explain why your else branch behaves differently.

Comment: @CBroe was able to fix it, I'm not sure if this is the correct solution though. turns out that I can't use the ajax callback function on my template to populate the post that's why I just created another function that will load the default posts. Also, thanks for pointing out the incorrect condition placements. Learned a lot! :)